# Greatest common divisor of two multiples of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and let $m = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_{k-1}^{e_{k-1}}p_k^{e_k}$ by unique prime factorization, where $p_i$ is distinct. Why is it true that $gcd(p_i^{e_i}, p_j^{e_j}) = 1$ for $i \neq j$?

Comment: Hint: by existence & uniqueness or prime factorizations the only primes dividing $p^n$ are $\,p\ \ $

Comment: To put Bill Dubuque's comment in the specific context of the question, the only prime that divides $p_i^{e_i}$ is $p_i$, and since $p_j$ is distinct from $p_i$, it will not divide $p_i^{e_i}$.

Comment: Sorry but I am probably missing some context. Why do we care about prime common divisors here?

Comment: Prime common divisors are important, ’cause if the gcd is not $1$, then there is a $k>0$ dividing both $m$ and $n$, so any prime dividing $k$ is a common prime divisor of $m$ and $n$. Now take the contrapositive.

Comment: We *always* care about prime factorizations and prime factors factors because they a the *single* thing that tells us what divides into a number.  This should be an *easy* question.  The only prime that divides into $p_i^k $ is $p_i $ and THEREFORE the only factors of $p_i^k $ are powers of $p_i $.  If two numbers have any factors in common, the number must be one whose only prime factors are prime factors of *both* numbers.  That should be obvious.